# Laravel cannot create new table field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I cannot migrate and make a new table field in `phpmyadmin` in my database it is giving me this error why?

my **Modal** name Setting

here is my modal as you can see I can't insert anything still coz I don't have my table in `phpmyadmin`.

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Setting extends Model
{
    //
}
```

my **Migration**

here is my migration

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('settings_code');
        $table->string('subject');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('settings');
}
```

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or
>   view already exists: 1050 Table 'clients' already exists (SQL: create
>   table `clients` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary
>   key, `client_code` varchar(191) not null, `client_name` varchar(191)
>   not null, `address` varchar(191) not null, `tel_no` varchar(191) not
>   null, `contact_person` varchar(191) not null, `mobile_no` varchar(191)
>   not null, `email_ad` varchar(191) not null, `website` varchar(191) not
>   null, `deleted_at` timestamp null, `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

I want to create a new table not client table but it is giving me this error. why?

Comment: use php artisan migrate:fresh it's will dropped all table and migrate new ones

Comment: Message is quite clear, table already exists. How are you calling your migrations? Can you edit your question and paste your migration? Wait "_I cannot create a new table field in phpmyadmin_" You're not using migrations but `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: There it is sorry im just in a hurry

Comment: That's not a modal, but a migration. And that's not for the table `clients`, but for `settings`. If you want to re-initiate your migration use `php artisan migrate:fresh` to drop all tables (and data!!!) and run all migrations from start

Comment: @kerbholz no I want to migrate and create new table in my phpmyadmin sorry

Comment: oh right ,... ill edit it again my modal has no code

Comment: there it is all edited please see

Comment: @kerbholz dude, why it worked all of a sudden when i do migrate:fresh? make a answer below i will mark your answer and one more.. why  php artisan migrate  didnt work? any explanation?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations `php artisan migrate:fresh` drops all existing tables (and thus data) and runs your migrations from the start. So no "duplicate" tables. @MD.JubairMizan commented "the solution" first, so he should get props for an answer

Comment: hey @kerbholz when i refresh, my data were removed. and when i register and login it creates an error why

Comment: Dear I have create an answer On this

Comment: We mentioned that "tables will be dropped"/"data will be lost". As for your error when registering/logging in please create a new question for that specific problem. And mention there _what_ error you get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run:`php artisan migrate:fresh`

**Be warned** This will remove anything stored within the database so ensure you have a Seeder setup to place any relevant content back into the database.

In the event you get an Specified key was too long error on the re migrate open AppServiceProvider and add:

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191); into the boot function
```

Ensure you add use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; at the top of the AppServiceProvider file

Comment: yes i did that and it worked but the problem is i cannot login anymore to my admin.. :(

Comment: even tho ill register as a different user i cannot login

Comment: It's remove all your Data you can make seeder for that . when you are migrate then you can seed your dummy data

Comment: yeah how can i seed?

Comment: in my case how can I call the seeder? is it only `php artisan make:seeder  'what is this table'  ` ?

Comment: It's will be better if you ask another question on it and get the answer on specific prob.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206038/what-is-database-seeding-in-laravel follow this stack

Answer (score 0):

hi try to romove your database from phpmyadmin and create again then run php artisan migrate  to login go to your table user and create a user manually in BD and in your model put fillable with your data stored